# Mineflayer bot keeps leaving the server when deployed with render

Tags: javascript, deployment, mineflayer

I made a simple AFK bot for my Aternos server using mineflayer. It seemed to be working fine when run locally from my computer. But when I tried to deploy it using render it just kept leaving and joining.
Here's my code:

```js
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer')


const botargs = {
  host: 'MY SMP ADDRESS',
  port: 24383,
  username: 'AFKBot',
  
};

function initBot() {
  bot = mineflayer.createBot(botargs)

  bot.once('spawn', () => {
    bot.chat("/tp @s 4 76 5")
  })


  bot.on('physicTick', lookAtNearestPlayer)
  bot.on('physicTick', () => {

    bot.setControlState('jump', true)
  })
  bot.on('end', () => {
    setTimeout(initBot, 5000)
  })
}


function lookAtNearestPlayer() {
  const playerFilter = (entity) => entity.type === 'player'
  const playerEntity = bot.nearestEntity(playerFilter)

  if (!playerEntity) return

  const pos = playerEntity.position.offset(0, playerEntity.height, 0)
  bot.lookAt(pos)
}
initBot()
```

Can anyone help, please